# How to pull out language via regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following two string:

```
s1 = 'Audio: Dolby Digital 5.1 (English)'
s2 = 'Audio: Stereo (English, French)'
```

I want to pull out the first language in each string. Here is what I have so far:

```
re.search(r'\s\((.+)', s1)
['English)']
```

How would I improve this to work on both of the above?

Comment: May I ask why you're using `findall()` instead of `search()` if you only want the first result?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 good point, that should be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this which will only find the first language and it is only a small tweak to your existing code

```
f=re.findall(r'\((\w+)', s1)
e=re.findall(r'\((\w+)', s2)
if f:
    print f
if e:
    print e


f = ['English']
e = ['English']
```

if you only want the first language then you should be using `search` instead like so

```
f = re.search(r'\((\w+)', s1)
e = re.search(r'\((\w+)', s2)
if f:
    print f.group(1)
if e:
    print e.group(1)
```

This will print a string rather than a list since it is only finding one thing

Comment: @David542 if this works for you then don't forget to mark it so others will know what worked for you in the future

Answer (score 1):

Widen the search to start the phrase with a parenthesis or comma+space, and end with a parenthesis or comma+space:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\s(?:\(|, )(.+)(?:\)|, )', s2)
['English, French']
```

The `?:` after a parenthesis indicates a non-capturing group.

You can then grab whichever language you're interested in with indexing.

Since the strings you're searching are actually pretty tidy, you can also do this without regex:

```
>>> s1.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(', ')[0]
'English'
>>> s2.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(', ')[0]
'English'
```

Comment: I think OP was looking for just the first language

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after posting. I then added the note about grabbing the first one with indexing (e.g. `results[0]`). Could be useful if the OP wants the other languages at some point.

Comment: Actually, if he only wants the first result, I'm not sure why he's using `findall()` instead of `search()`.

Comment: possibly a mistake. OP clearly has some issues with regex so he/she may not know the difference

Answer (score 0):

Assuming languages are always at the end, surrounded by brackets and listed with `,`:

```
(?<=\()\w+(?=(?:, \w+)*\)$)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/rW7bH8/1)

The idea is:

1. `(?<=\()` - the string should be preceded by an opening bracket(`(`)
2. `\w+` - the language itself is a sequence of letters
3. `(?=(?:, \w+)*\)$)` - after it, there can be zero or more other languages, separated with *comma* and *space* and after closing the bracket(`)`) leaves us at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this simple modification of your regular expression:

```
\s\(([^,\n\)]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lA5eZ2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the text after the first LParen and before the first comma.  So, a regex that would match this is:

```
\(([^,]*),
```

(Your answer will be in group 1)
Finally, I'd like to point you to https://www.debuggex.com/, which will help you easily visualize your regex questions.